# MVC Ajax BeginForm validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-validation

I have a Bootstrap modal that makes an insert. I am using Ajax BeginForm and I have problem with the validation. Normal validation like: required fields works great. My problem is that I have a server validation and when it goes into the controller and does not pass my custom validation I tried to return the partialview with the model or even a json but I am not able to trigger the validation on the modal. I googled a lot and I was not able to solve my problem.

Here is the code

```
public class ContactDto
{
    public decimal IdContact{ get; set; }
    public decimal? CounterpartyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }   
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult EditContact(ContactDto contact)
{
    if (CustomValidation(code) && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _dbManager.CreateCode(code);

        //return RedirectToAction("Details", "Counterparties", new { id = code.CodeCounterpartyId });
        return Json(new { Data = "Ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { Data = "Nok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Modal with Ajax:

```
@using System.Globalization
@model UpdateTabs.Models.ContactDto

<div id="EditContactModalDiv" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    .......

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditContact", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "ValidateKeys"}, new { id = "formCreateContact" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            ......

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            <br/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

            ......      
        }   

    .......

    </div>
</div>
```

and the Jquery part:

```
function ValidateKeys(result) {
    if (result.Ok) {
        $('#CreateCodeModalDiv').modal('hide');
    } else {

        alert("Model is invalid !");
        $('#CreateCodeModalDiv').modal('show');
    }
}
```

and until here is working, but after here I don't know what to do to trigger the validation message for.

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: turn on your validation summary ??

Comment: I have already done that: @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: Have you tried refreshing you DOM content using $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(result)); ?

Comment: yes I tried this, but putting the name of the field instead of result. And also $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#id") where id is the id of the form. Nothing...

Comment: confirmed, I just tried it again, changing the controller with Action result instead of json and passing the model and the adding the error to the ModelState and nothing...